# Pandas - datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame el cual contiene las datos históricos de una determinada criptomoneda:

```
    Open time   Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Close time  Quote asset volume  Number of trades    Taker buy base asset volume Taker buy quote asset volume    Ignore
0   1636243200000   82.55   84.84   81.49   82.93   40269.64    1636246799999   3.357068e+06    10965   21357.25    1.781115e+06    0
1   1636246800000   82.96   84.63   82.48   83.00   17262.62    1636250399999   1.441213e+06    5547    8283.38 6.913994e+05    0
2   1636250400000   82.98   85.80   82.93   85.00   25355.42    1636253999999   2.141665e+06    7418    14652.05    1.237636e+06    0
3   1636254000000   85.09   85.82   83.12   83.31   16386.62    1636257599999   1.383310e+06    4446    7280.19 6.148422e+05    0
4   1636257600000   83.26   83.73   81.21   81.64   29309.13    1636261199999   2.406924e+06    5313    11486.89    9.418435e+05    0
5   1636261200000   81.64   81.96   80.32   80.44   13879.05    1636264799999   1.125639e+06    2901    7335.87 5.956194e+05    0
6   1636264800000   80.42   80.91   79.47   79.65   17847.36    1636268399999   1.428264e+06    2964    7533.43 6.028900e+05    0
7   1636268400000   79.66   80.07   79.32   79.93   10127.39    1636271999999   8.075282e+05    2068    5903.71 4.709790e+05    0
8   1636272000000   79.90   80.09   78.29   79.24   23787.10    1636275599999   1.878077e+06    3819    14402.53    1.135488e+06    0
9   1636275600000   79.24   80.27   78.28   79.99   16217.80    1636279199999   1.287065e+06    2946    8406.34 6.671516e+05    0
10  1636279200000   79.93   79.99   78.10   78.47   21454.87    1636282799999   1.691778e+06    3632    12606.90    9.933715e+05    0
11  1636282800000   78.46   78.67   77.61   78.67   19523.54    1636286399999   1.526579e+06    4010    11144.48    8.716531e+05    0
12  1636286400000   78.61   78.98   77.10   77.43   11627.38    1636289999999   9.066539e+05    2521    4109.77 3.205205e+05    0
13  1636290000000   77.48   78.25   77.43   77.91   12692.64    1636293599999   9.885195e+05    2190    6517.61 5.076344e+05    0
14  1636293600000   77.88   78.56   77.81   78.31   12063.24    1636297199999   9.442264e+05    2059    6244.97 4.888057e+05    0
15  1636297200000   78.31   78.98   77.70   78.03   14765.56    1636300799999   1.156426e+06    2509    6557.61 5.139842e+05    0
16  1636300800000   78.11   79.64   78.09   78.81   15518.51    1636304399999   1.226544e+06    3741    7899.64 6.241283e+05    0
17  1636304400000   78.81   79.16   78.03   78.35   7863.37 1636307999999   6.172382e+05    1610    4377.15 3.434900e+05    0
18  1636308000000   78.40   78.52   77.81   77.89   8346.67 1636311599999   6.522344e+05    1646    3218.32 2.516946e+05    0
19  1636311600000   77.82   79.56   77.82   78.95   11437.50    1636315199999   8.983021e+05    2237    7553.15 5.932930e+05    0
20  1636315200000   78.95   78.97   78.24   78.41   4774.38 1636318799999   3.750340e+05    1178    1982.97 1.557362e+05    0
21  1636318800000   78.44   79.39   78.41   79.06   6125.10 1636322399999   4.832226e+05    1210    3150.25 2.483917e+05    0
22  1636322400000   78.98   79.25   77.15   77.23   10189.78    1636325999999   7.972956e+05    2025    3411.71 2.677758e+05    0
23  1636326000000   77.18   77.40   75.70   76.30   38290.69    1636329599999   2.926428e+06    5720    20429.67    1.561560e+06    0
```

Mi duda guarda relación con la columna 'Open time' por lo que carece de importancia que falten datos en las columnas siguientes.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿alguien sabe cual es ese formato de tiempo y como pasarlo a un formato legible?. Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus columnas de tiempo están en [`tiempo unix`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix#:%7E:text=Tiempo%20Unix%20o%20Tiempo%20POSIX,1970%2C%20sin%20contar%20segundos%20intercalares.) por lo que significa una cantidad de tiempo desde el epoch.

En tu caso veo que son milisegundos, por lo que para convertirlos puedes utilizar `pd.to_datetime` pasandole `unit="ms"` (ya que por defecto busca nanosegundos).

```javascript
df['Open time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open time'], unit="ms")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!